# RUBY: defined?(klass) seeing a local-variable instead of constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am running into an issue, where I need to **check if a class exists**.  However, I am **passing the class to a variable** and trying to check it from there.

My issue is I need to pass the actual constant for **defined?()** to work, but I'm passing a variable, so instead of seeing a constant, it sees a method or variable.

`obj` is a rails model instance, for example, a specific `User`, or a specific `Car`.

```
  def present(obj, presenter_class=nil, view_context=nil)
    klass = presenter_class || "#{obj.class}Presenter".constantize
    if defined?(klass) == 'constant' && klass.class == Class 
      klass.new(obj, view_context)
    else
      warn("#{self}: #{klass} is not a defined class, no presenter used")
      obj
    end
  end
```

Pry Output:

```
[1] pry(ApplicationPresenter)> defined?(klass) 
=> "local-variable"
```

I tried the below, but I get a method back...

```
[18] pry(ApplicationPresenter)> defined?("UserPresenter".constantize)
=> "method"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How about `klass.is_a?(Class)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I'm sure this is an idiotic question (sorry), but isn't everything a `Class`? After all this time, I find I'm still just learning ruby.

Comment: No, can be methods or as the above shows variables,etc

Comment: Is it really necessary that you handle this `else` case to show the warning and continue the program? Why don't you want it to throw an error in that case?

Comment: All Ruby objects are instances (members) of a class. Variables, however, are not objects. If the argument of [Object#defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) holds what may be the name of a local variable, the method will return `"local-variable"` if a local variable with that name exists; else it will return `nil`. To my knowledge this is the only situation where a reference to a local variable concerns the variable itself as opposed to the object it holds.

Comment: @maxpleaner because there are some objects that don't have presenters

Comment: But then why couldn't you just do a nil check? Read up on duck typing - explicit type checks aren't something done often in Ruby

Comment: @jvillian: "I'm sure this is an idiotic question (sorry), but isn't everything a `Class`? After all this time, I find I'm still just learning ruby" - No, there are lots of things that aren't classes. For example, `1` is an `Integer` not a class. `'Hello'` is a `String`, `1.2` is a `Float`, `[]` is an `Array`, `{}` is a `Hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently [Object#defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) does not the thing that you hoped it would do.

> tests whether or not expression refers to anything recognizable (literal object, local variable that has been initialized, method name visible from the current scope, etc.). The return value is nil if the expression cannot be resolved. Otherwise, the return value provides information about the expression.

Your goal looks like you are rebuilding what the draper gem is doing with `.decorate`... Don't forget that most of the gems are open source and you can use that for trying things on your own. See for example [the `decorator_class` method from them](https://github.com/drapergem/draper/blob/157eb955072a941e6455e0121fca09a989fcbc21/lib/draper/decoratable.rb#L71)

```rb
decorator_name = "#{prefix}Decorator"
decorator_name_constant = decorator_name.safe_constantize
return decorator_name_constant unless decorator_name_constant.nil?
```

They use the method `safe_constantize` and this apparently returns nil when the constant is not available.

```rb
2.6.5 :007 > class UserPresenter; end;
 => nil 
2.6.5 :008 > 'UserPresenter'.safe_constantize
 => UserPresenter 
2.6.5 :009 > 'ForgottenPresenter'.safe_constantize
 => nil
```

To me that looks exactly like what you need, and it also [safer than using constantize](http://gavinmiller.io/2016/the-safesty-way-to-constantize/)

```rb
  def present(obj, presenter_class=nil, view_context=nil)
    klass = presenter_class || "#{obj.class}Presenter".safe_constantize
    if klass != nil
      klass.new(obj, view_context)
    else
      warn("#{self}: #{klass} is not a defined class, no presenter used")
      obj
    end
  end
```

Comment: It is more common and more economical to reference a method's document by writing, for example, `[Object#defined?](URL here)`, which appears as [Object#defined?](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F).

Comment: Can you explain this more? What do you mean [Object#defined?](url here), Can you post an example specific to this issue?